# Etymology of "[Where/What/Why] in the world" idiom?

Tags: etymology

I've searched the internet and found definitions, but I cannot figure out when this would have EVER meant anything. Any ideas? Specifically, the type of phrase I am referring to is "What in the world were you thinking?" or "Why in the world would I want to do that?" In those questions, "in the world" is used to emphasize how ridiculous the OP must have been when making such a decision.

Comment: Note that there is the similar expression "... why on earth ...", and also expressions such as "What in Heaven's name were you thinking?"  The latter mildly suggests that "... in the world ..." may be yet another attempt to "soften" oaths so that they do not reference &deity.

Comment: It's just straight, literal meaning, at least before becoming a time-worn phrase. If I ask "*What in the back yard is blue?*", the scope is the back yard. "*What in the world*" is similar, with a wider scope. Ditto, "*what on Earth*", "*what in the universe*",...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*What in the world were you thinking?* is a rhetorical question. That means it is actually a statement:

> In this world (in actual reality) there is nothing that could explain you thoughts.

Similarly, *why in the world would I do that?* is rhetorical for:

> In this world there is no reason why I would do that.

So basically, adding *in the world* to a rhetorical question implies that what the person was doing, thinking, saying or asking is not in the realm of this world: it is *out of this world*, it is *unrealistic*, it is *absurd*.

Comment: I sort of understood the meaning, I was just wondering where it came from. Are you saying the source is not that big a deal, and that it is simply a rewording into a rhetorical format?

Comment: If I interpret the meaning as I understand it, the _origin_ of the meaning would be the origin of the words that make up the phrase. I don't see anything heavily idiomatic in the phrase, the meaning seems to be quite literal.

Comment: Ok, now that you put it that way... it makes more sense.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. I would merely observe that the extra syllables provided by what is essentially an empty phrase (or almost so) enables the person indulging in the rhetoric to make more of a meal of their point: they have more time in which to browbeat the other person, more scope for emphatically stressing certain words, a longer focus of attention on themselves during which they can wag their fingers, roll their eyes and sigh, etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20in%20the%20world%2CWhy%20in%20the%20world&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhy%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0) the expressions ( What/Why in the world) have been used for at least the last two centuries. The earliest  instance I could find dates back to [1733](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22what%20in%20the%20world%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1724,cd_max:1742&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=37nGVJqgIonjywPXmoEQ):

> This seems so fair, so exact, that what in the World could have a better Face? Yet for all this, the *Scots* do not fail to complain of him, and affirm that he had regard only to his own Interests. Therefore to have a clear and distinct Idea of this Affair, 'tis worth while to look into the Complaints of the *Scots*, and to see on what they are founded, tho this is what Mr. *Rymer*'s Collection takes no notice of.

I don't think they have a specific etymology but they are just a way to give emphasis to what one is saying.!

Comment: The Google Books Ngram snippet had a couple of typos in it, which I fixed—and then I filled out the two sentences cited in the quotation. You can see a fuller version of the quotation in [Acta Regia](https://books.google.it/books?id=hHS5i_IYxBkC&pg=PA73&dq=%22Affair,+%27tis+worth+while+to+look+into%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=rPXGVIzrEc33oATf1ICwCw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Affair%2C%20%27tis%20worth%20while%20to%20look%20into%22&f=false)—this particular edition published in 1726, by the way.

Comment: I can't find the date in your link!

Comment: It's at the bottom of the title page: MDCCXXVI.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those expressions that is so old that it is almost literally translated from Latin, as in "[*Nulla in mundo pax sincera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulla_in_mundo_pax_sincera)"  ("In this world there is no honest peace.") which is based on an anonymous, ancient poem.   The sense of "in the world" being a synonym for "to exist" is found in the Roman legal proverb: "*Quod non est in actis, non est in mundo*:"  "That which is not in the statutes is not in the world."

A similar idiom is "[It's Greek to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_to_me)," which comes from the Latin via Shakespeare.